# Does anyone know this geometric sans font used in the Photo Bulk app?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I used this font to make a watermark using the Photo Bulk app on a mac, but I can't remember what's the name of it. I tried to find it using some web sites but none gave me the right answer. I couldn't use What The Font though, since the site seems to be broken.

Here is the watermark:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ONwSJLR.jpg]

Comment: It looks like you get to choose what font is used when you apply the watermark, so it should say what font you have been using. I am checking out the app [PhotoBulk](http://mac.eltima.com/bulk-image-editor.html). Are you using a different app?

Comment: 'Some websites'? Please ensure that you have tried all websites in our [font-identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366). WhatTheFont works fine for me, though.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [Frontage Regular](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jurizaech/frontage/regular/) to me:
[image]

[image]

It's got the slightly angled sides to the 'M' and the wider 'A' that Neutra Display is lacking.

Comment: Nice find! This is certainly a better answer.

Comment: I used in on a project not long ago, so I recognised it right away.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like House Industries' [Neutra Display Bold](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/neutraface) or a similar font in the family. There might be some minor differences (that 'A' in your version looks a little wider, for example), but this is probably what you want.

[image: Neutra screenshot]

Comment: Neutra display Bold looks indeed very similar to the font I used but I can't find it in the app's font list. The one that look the most like the photo I posted is Trebuchet MS. I guess the dev. team removed the Neutra Display font.. Thanks for your help !